# How to fix the width and height of this horizontal chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a chart horizontally generated with chart js. The problem that I'm having is that the width and height are not being fixed when data changes.

Here are some pictures:

[image]

[image]

JS code:

```js
ListNomCo = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
ListDataCo = [1, 2, 3, 4];
myHorizontalChartBar = new Chart($("#myHorizontalChartBar")[0], {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ListNomCo,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dossiers',
      data: ListDataCo,
      backgroundColor: '#FD8B6F',
      borderColor: '#D54A2C',
      borderWidth: 1,
      width: 2
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          display: false
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        padding: 20,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        categoryPercentage: 1.5,
        barPercentage: 0.3,
        categorySpacing: 0
      }]
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div class="row mx-0 mt-3">
  <div class="col-7" id="containerChartFiltrage">
    <canvas id="myHorizontalChartBar" style="height:300px;position: relative;top: 50%;" class="chart"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I fix the width of the chart to work with any kind of data?

Comment: What charting library is this?

Comment: @WillardSolutions chart js Version: 2.4.0

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barthickness

Comment: yes i mean how to change this values to have fixed width bar

Answer (score 0):

If you would like it to be relative to the view port size, then you should add the following class to all the children elements:

```
.foo{
    width:100vw;
}
```

I hope this helps!

For the next time; only show the code that matters, and put the snippets inside one single snippet, so that your post is easier to understand and not as clustered.

Comment: i don't have class foo

Comment: @mecab1995 foo is just a place holder just make that class

Comment: where i make it